# Error in optim(): searching for global minimum for a univariate function

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to optmize a function in R

The function is the Likelihood function of negative binominal when estimating only `mu` parameter. This should not be a problem since the function clearly has just one point of maximum. But, I am not being able to reach the desirable result.

The function to be optmized is:

```
EMV <- function(data, par) {

    Mi  <- par
    Phi <- 2
    N   <- NROW(data)

    Resultado <- log(Mi/(Mi + Phi))*sum(data) + N*Phi*log(Phi/(Mi + Phi))
    return(Resultado)
}
```

Data is a vector of negative binomial variables with parameters 2 and 2

```
data <- rnegbin(10000, mu = 2, theta = 2)
```

When I plot the function having `mu` as variable with the following code:

```
x <- seq(0.1, 100, 0.02)
z <- EMV(data,0.1)
for (aux in x) {z <- rbind(z, EMV(data,aux))}
z <- z[2:NROW(z)]
plot(x,z)
```

I get the following curve:

[image: Generated Curve]

And the maximum value of z is close to parameter value --> 2

```
x[which.max(z)]
```

But the optimization is not working with BFGS

```
Error in optim(par = theta, fn = EMV, data = data, method = "BFGS") : 
non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

And is not going to right value using SANN, for example:

```
$par
[1] 5.19767e-05

$value
[1] -211981.8

$counts
function gradient 
   10000       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

The questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a way to tell `optim` that the param should be bigger than 0?
3. Is there a way to tell `optim` that I want to maximize the function? (I am afraid the `optim` is trying to minimize and is going to a very small value where function returns smallest values)

Comment: Thanks. I used `optim(par = theta, fn = EMV, data = data, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1E5)` and I am getting 1E5 as result. It seems, the optim is minimizing the function in the interval.

Comment: Please formulate your comment as an answer that I would be glad to accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure... Take your time. My problem was solved already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Minimization or Maximization?**

Although `?optim` says it can do maximization, but that is in a bracket, so minimization is default:

```
fn: A function to be minimized (or maximized) ...
```

Thus, if we want to maximize an objective function, we need to multiply an `-1` to it, and then minimize it. This is quite a common situation. In statistics we often want to find maximum log likelihood, so to use `optim()`, we have no choice but to minimize the negative log likelihood.

**Which method to use?**

If we only do 1D minimization, we should use method `"Brent"`. This method allows us to specify a lower bound and an upper bound of search region. Searching will start from one bound, and search toward the other, until it hit the minimum, or it reach the boundary. Such specification can help you to constrain your parameters. For example, you don't want `mu` to be smaller than 0, then just set `lower = 0`.

When we move to 2D or higher dimension, we should resort to `"BFGS"`. In this case, if we want to constrain one of our parameters, say `a`, to be positive, we need to take log transform `log_a = log(a)`, and reparameterize our objective function using `log_a`. Now, `log_a` is free of constraint. The same goes when we want constrain multiple parameters to be positive.

**How to change your code?**

```
EMV <- function(data, par) {

    Mi  <- par
    Phi <- 2
    N   <- NROW(data)

    Resultado <- log(Mi/(Mi + Phi))*sum(data) + N*Phi*log(Phi/(Mi + Phi))
    return(-1 * Resultado)
}

optim(par = theta, fn = EMV, data = data, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1E5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The help file for `optim` says: "By default optim performs minimization, but it will maximize if control$fnscale is negative." So if you either multiply your function output by -1 or change the control object input, you should get the right answer.