# `optimize()`: Maximum likelihood estimation of rate of an exponential distribution

Tags: r, mle

I'm really struggling with understanding MLE calculations in R.

If I have a random sample of size 6 from the `exp(λ)` distribution results in observations:

```
x <- c(1.636, 0.374, 0.534, 3.015, 0.932, 0.179)
```

I calculated out the MLE as follows

```
mean(x)
```

and got 1.111667 (I'm not 100% certain I did this part right).

But when I try to code numeric calculation using R I either get errors or an answer that doesn't match.

```
lik <- function(lam) prod(dexp(x))   # likelihood function
nlik <- function(lam) -lik(lam)      # negative-likelihood function
optimize(nlik, x)
```

gives me

```
#$minimum
#[1] 3.014928
#
#$objective
#[1] -0.001268399
```

Originally I had

```
lik <-function(lam) prod(dexp(x, lambda=lam))   # likelihood function
nlik <- function(lam) -lik(lam)      # negative-likelihood function
optim(par=1, nlik)   # minimize nlik with starting parameter value=1
```

But I kept getting

```
#Error in dexp(x, lambda = lam) : 
#  unused argument (lambda = lam)
#In addition: Warning message:
#In optim(par = 1, nlik) :
#  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
#use "Brent" or optimize() directly
```

Comment: Your function does not use its argument `lam`: it will return the same value, whatever you call it with. Perhaps you want it to be `prod(dexp(lam))`? On the other hand, your previous version called `dexp` with an argument named `lambda`. `?dexp` reveals that this function does not have an argument with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is your observation vector

```
x <- c(1.636, 0.374, 0.534, 3.015, 0.932, 0.179)
```

I'm not sure why you minimize negative likelihood directly; often we work with negative **log** likelihood.

```
nllik <- function (lambda, obs) -sum(dexp(obs, lambda, log = TRUE))
```

When using `optimize`, set a lower and upper bound:

```
optimize(nllik, lower = 0, upper = 10, obs = x)

#$minimum
#[1] 0.8995461
#
#$objective
#[1] 6.635162
```

This is not too far away from sample mean: 1.11, given that you only have 6 observations which is insufficient for a close estimate anyway.

---

It is pretty sufficient to use `optimize` here, as you work with univariate optimization. If you want to use `optim`, set `method = "Brent"`. You can read [Error in optim(): searching for global minimum for a univariate function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37738423/4891738) for more.

Comment: I have a very similar solution except it's a more rough estimate. I iteratively applied the function `f <- function(x=sim, theta) -sum(dexp(x, rate=theta, log=TRUE))` over `lambdas = seq(f0, 50, length=n)`. Then, I put `lambdas` and `f(lambdas)` in a single data frame called `res` and perform the query `res$lambdas[which(res$log_lik == max(res$log_lik))]`.

Comment: The optimize function finds the MLE for the rate parameter and the mean is the inverse of the rate (e.g. 1/0.899=1.112). So the sample mean is exactly the inverse of the MLE estimate for the rate; there is no numerically discrepancy due to only 6 observations.